# change an image file based on screen size using min-width

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tailwind-css

I need this to change from the current image file to a desktop image when the screen size reaches a minimum width of 375px . im using tailwind css as my pre processor.

```
 <img src="images/bg-curve-mobile.svg" />
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution switching can be done using the [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset) and [`sizes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/sizes) attributes. (However, this is defeated on displays that have a pixel density of 2.) See the MDN article [Responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) for more info.

```
<img
  srcset="images/bg-curve-mobile.svg 375w, images/bg-curve-desktop.svg 800w"
  sizes="(max-width: 375px) 375px, 800px"
  src="images/bg-curve-desktop.svg"
  alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

While this can also be done using JS, here's a css solution that works. You can replace the url with the file paths of the images in your project.

html:

```
<div class='container'>
  <img />
</div>
```

css:

```
img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%; // this makes our image responsive. 
  
  
  content: url(url_pc)
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  img{
    content: url(url_mobile)
  }
}
```

Comment: Could I use that in my input.css file sense its a tailwind project?

Comment: If its a css file, then sure why not. Just give a unique class name to the image tag, and the container as well